# How i can use the facebook like in my wordpress in order to show the post?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I want to use the facebook like button us an if statement. before show a post  i want first the user click the like button in order to see the post. how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a PHP script for sale on CodeCanyon that does exactly that: 
http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-like-locker-like-to-read-plugin/166051

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this company?

Comment: Even if I had, would there be a problem? Isn´t the script exactly what the asker is looking for? Did I include an affiliate link?..ah and no, I don´t have an affiliation with this company, just trying to be helpful...

Comment: It's fine as you don't, but if had had one then you would have had to declare it. I thought to ask as was your only post at the time, and a single post from a previously unknown source to promote a commercial product is usually from someone with a vested interest, and no knowledge of the general practices regarding such. Since this isn't the case, all is well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's possible. In fact, it might violate Facebook's Terms of Service. Rather, consider adding the Facebook like plugin and have it display at the top of the post.

Comment: you need to have a reputation level of 15. feel free to ask someone else to vote this up. more importantly, i'm glad i was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Note to Readers: If you are looking for the download to this file you can grab it here: http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-like-locker-like-to-read-plugin/166051?ref=tylerquinn

I am the developer of this premium WordPress plugin, I just wanted to let you know you can get instant access to the plugin, support, and free updates when download it through CodeCanyon.

It does comply with Facebook's TOS, and is NOT a method of click jacking which is what facebook frowns upon.